# SQL Table Column that uses input from Another Column in Same Table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, dataset

I want to have a column in table which calculates the value depending on the other column in the same table.

For example,
I have "Validity" Table with Columns "DateManufactured", "DateExpires"
The Date Expires column must calculate value suppose adding 30 days for Datemanufactured.
How Can we do this in Visual Studio2010->DataSet Design-> DataTable Column-> Properties->Expression
See relevant Image [here](http://tinypic.com/r/ndlanm/6)

What could be the possible expression for this in terms of SQL Server Expressions?
Please Suggest optimal Solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `DateExpires` is _always_ 30 days after `DateManufactured` then perhaps you shouldn't be storing it.  A search for "database normalization" should put you on a better track.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 30, '15 Dec 1988')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dateadd(day,30,getdate())
```

this will take the current date(getdate())
add 30 days  to it.

Comment: That is not my requirement Ruzbeh. Please read the updated question clearly and see the image placed in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a stored procedure to insert your data into your table with parameters of the values that needs to be inserted. you can then do your calculation based on your date parameter. Example:

```
Create Procedure InsertValidity
(
  @City varchar(20),
  @Area varchar(20),
  ...
  @DatePosted datetime,
  ...
  @UserID
)

as

declare @DurationFrom datetime
set @DurationFrom = (select DATEADD(dd,30,@DatePosted)

insert into Validity (City, Area, ..., DatePosted, ... UserID)
values(@City, @Area, ..., @DatePosted,...@DurationFrom,...@UserID)
```

This should solve your problem. Just complete the script by replacing the ... with your other data then execute the stored procedure in your application.